# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate resets defaults in my MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model in my MongoDB database titled "Reviews" that contains a field called "reviewLikes". When someone clicks on a "like" button on the UI, I use findByIdAndUpdate to increase the reviewLikes by 1. This works, however, when it happens, it also resets a number of defaults in the database. Is there something different that I should be using here to prevent the resetting? Including the code that is updating the field below.

```
exports.updateOne = (Model) =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const doc = await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    });

    if (!doc) {
      return next(new AppError('No document found with that ID!', 404));
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'Success',
      data: {
        data: doc,
      },
    });
  });
```

What is getting reset? In a separate model, the review is used to calculate a "ratingsAverage". Including the model below. This number gets reset to the default value of "3".

```
const shipSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  shipName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A ship name is required.'],
    maxlength: [60, 'That ship name is too long, please try again.'],
    unique: [true, 'Ship name already exists.'],
  },
  slug: String,
  builtDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Ship built date is required.'],
  },
  ratingsAverage: {
    type: Number,
    default: 3,
    min: [1, 'Minimum rating is 1. Please try again.'],
    max: [5, 'Max rating is 5. Please try again.'],
  },
  ratingsQuantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  ratingsAverageDining: {
    type: Number,
    default: 3,
    min: [1, 'Minimum rating is 1. Please try again.'],
    max: [5, 'Max rating is 5. Please try again.'],
  },
  ratingsAverageCabin: {
    type: Number,
    default: 3,
    min: [1, 'Minimum rating is 1. Please try again.'],
    max: [5, 'Max rating is 5. Please try again.'],
  },
  ratingsAverageKids: {
    type: Number,
    default: 3,
    min: [1, 'Minimum rating is 1. Please try again.'],
    max: [5, 'Max rating is 5. Please try again.'],
  },
  ratingsAverageValue: {
    type: Number,
    default: 3,
    min: [1, 'Minimum rating is 1. Please try again.'],
    max: [5, 'Max rating is 5. Please try again.'],
  },
  ratingsAverageEnt: {
    type: Number,
    default: 3,
    min: [1, 'Minimum rating is 1. Please try again.'],
    max: [5, 'Max rating is 5. Please try again.'],
  },
  maidenVoyageDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Maiden voyage date is required.'],
  },
  cruiseLine: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Ship cruise line is required.'],
  },
  maxCapacity: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Max ship capacity is required.'],
  },
  shipCost: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Ship cost is required.'],
  },
  shipBuilderName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Ship builder name is required.'],
  },
  shipWeight: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Ship weight is required.'],
  },
  shipStatus: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      values: ['active', 'inactive'],
      message: 'Ship status must be active or inactive.',
    },
    required: [true, 'Ship status is required.'],
  },
  shipRegistry: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Location of ship registry is required.'],
  },
  shipIdentification: {
    shipCallsign: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Ship callsign is required.'],
      unique: [true, 'Call sign already exists.'],
    },
    shipIMONumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'Ship IMO number is required.'],
      unique: [true, 'IMO number already exists.'],
    },
    shipMMSINumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'Ship MMSI number is required.'],
      unique: [true, 'MMSI number already exists.'],
    },
  },
  shipPhoto: {
    type: String,
    default: 'default.jpg',
  },
});

//Virtual populate
shipSchema.virtual('reviews', {
  ref: 'Review',
  foreignField: 'ship',
  localField: '_id',
});

shipSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.shipPhoto = `${this.shipName}.jpg`;
  this.shipPhoto = this.shipPhoto.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase();
  next();
});

shipSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.slug = slugify(this.shipName, { lower: true });
  next();
});

shipSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.ratingsAverage > 4.5) {
    this.starDisplay = 10;
  }
  next();
});

const Ship = mongoose.model('Ship', shipSchema);

module.exports = Ship;
```

Comment: what does this mean ? > resets a number of defaults in the database

Comment: Sorry. Edited to include more detail.

Comment: you have to use ` {$set:{req.body}}`...

Comment: Check what is your `req.body`, maybe it contains that number.